# mp4 with pixel format yuvj420p won't play in Chrome 17, but plays in Safari, IE etc

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, mp4, x264

File is from a Nikon D3s (mov) converted with ffmpeg to mp4.
Working without problems with all other files (avi, flv, mp4 etc)

Please see file: http://shootitlive.s3.amazonaws.com/output.mp4
(Same non working result in Chrome when served from diffrent hosts, and always works in Safari and with flash in Firefox, Chromium)

> /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i nonworking.MOV -acodec libfaac -ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -crf 30 -threads 0 -s 768x576 -aspect 1.33333333333 -ar 48000 output.mp4

Cant find anything strange with (but dont really know what to look for):

```
ffmpeg -v 5 -i filename -f null - 2>error.log`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: chrome 17 is "old" The chrome auto-update makes older chrome versions really seldom.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think your problem is the pixel format.

From [your Chrome bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117368), the working video (working.mp4) has pix_fmt=yuv420p.  The non-working video (qt_output.mp4) has pix_fmt=yuv**j**420p.  In my testing, converting the problematic video to yuv makes it play.  Converting the working video to yuvj makes it not play.

I'm not sure why my analysis of the pixel format differs from Alek's on the Chrome bug report, but that made the difference for me.

Try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to your ffmpeg command.

Comment: This fix is also required when creating a video from jpeg frames (e.g. `ffmpeg -i frames%5d.jpg out.mp4` => `ffmpeg -i frames%5d.jpg -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4` )

Comment: this "-pix_fmt" flag helped me out after a night's struggle. Big thanks for this thread. Guys who reads this, and are having problems with e.g. Google Chrome browser not being able to play your encoded MP4 files — this is still an issue now, in the year 2013.

Comment: @user1971474 Almost a year later and I am having this problem too.

Comment: Those goo.gl links seem dead.

Comment: 2017: Android MediaPlayer class can't play yuvj420p. Thanks for the fix!

Answer (score 3):

Please read [chromium bug #117368](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117368), in which a developer explains that yuvj420p will not be supported soon:

> Indeed, chromium doesn't support yuvj420p.
>
> Generally we don't support video formats (or codecs) that aren't very widely used, because the support burden (maintaining code quality, fixing bugs, security reviews, etc) is out of proportion with user benefit (relative to everything else we can spend our time/energy on).
>
> Closing as WorkingAsIntended.  If the format becomes more widely popular we can reconsider including support for it.
> If there's another issue here that I'm missing, please reopen.

Comment: [@marca is the one who filed that bug report](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591959/mp4-wont-play-in-chrome-17-but-plays-in-safari-ie-etc/9642466#comment12213806_9592095).  The StackOverflow circle is complete.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing that can be done here, it's a browser issue you're linking to a raw file.
You really need to use an HTML5/FLASH/JS or other video player inside of an HTML document.

This will work in all HTML5-capable browsers
:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <video height="250" width="320">
        <source src="http://shootitlive.s3.amazonaws.com/output.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is with the mp4 file and with Chrome. Please see http://goo.gl/ZdYZK (index.html that loads the mp4) from Chrome and then from any other html5/mp4 capable browsers and you will see the video file play in all other browsers but not in Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't load on my android web kit browser either ;) I still suggest embedding it.

Comment: But it is embedded - goo.gl/ZdYZK (index.html that loads the mp4)

Comment: Care to show page source for it? I can't see it as its redirecting me to the mp4. Since you're using ffmpeg you may need to move the moov atom to the front of the file. There's an air app that does it somewhere out there. Referenced on flow player.org

Comment: We're using qt-faststart to move the moov atom. We're transcoding many, many videos daily that plays fine in our html5 player (mp4) or in flash in browsers not supporting mp4/html5. But this video fails and only in Chrome. Ive updated the html5 video embed with controls - http://goo.gl/Yct2k  Any ideas?

Comment: I think your video tag is wrong, not sure if that's the issue, try changing it to <video height="480" width="720" preload controls>, The preload may fix it, but I think controls="controls" is incorrect

Comment: The problem is with the video file and i wonder how this can be as it's encoded with same ffmpeg parameters that we use daily. And the strange thing is that it plays perfect in all other browsers (native html5/mp4 or with flash for browsers that dont support it). Here's a link with same html5 video embed displaying another video (from iPhone) compressed to mp4 - http://goo.gl/2lnyz (which works in Chrome as well) Any ideas what can be wrong with the video and why all other browsers, except Chrome can play this file http://goo.gl/Yct2k

Comment: @marca I would suggest submitting a bug report with all of the ffmpeg parameters you're using to encode the video. It must be a chrome bug as you said other WebKit browsers are working just fine (safari, chromium) Maybe the version of WebKit chrome 17 uses has a bug?

Comment: Thanks, it's been added. Here's the url: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=117368